# How to use JavaScript to query the $type of a MongoDB item?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database which has quite an unstructured layout. What I would like to do in my "app.js" file is determine what BSON type I have. If it's an array, look at what it is an array of, and from there, there will be two possible options: object or string. Depending on which it is, I want to do different things.

So currently, as I'm testing, I have the following:

```
app.get("/db", function(req, res) {
    Field.find({}, function(err, foundFields){
        // This is where I would like to query the type. 
    });
});
```

The idea is basically to iterate through the database and get deeper in different branches of the database, until you reach an array of strings, which will be at different depths depending on the branch.

What I have found so far is that I probably need to use "$type" in some sense, but I can't figure out how to use that to get a type from the level I am at, and to then check it against 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    const db = client.db("mydb");
    const collection = db.collection("items");
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err;
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            if (Array.isArray(doc.fieldName)) {
                if (typeof doc.fieldName[0] === 'object') {
                    // do something when array elements are objects
                } else if (typeof doc.fieldName[0] === 'string') {
                    // do something when array elements are strings
                }
            }
        });
        client.close();
    });
});
```

In this example, the code is connecting to a MongoDB instance running on the localhost on the default port 27017, and then selecting the 'mydb' as database and 'items' as collection.

Once the connection is established, it is using the find method to retrieve all the documents, and use the javascript method forEach to loop through the array of documents.

Inside the forEach loop, the if statement is using javascript's Array.isArray method to check whether the "fieldName" field is an array or not.

If it is an array, it uses the typeof operator to check the type of the first element of the array.
Depending on whether the elements are objects or strings, it will run the corresponding block of code.

Comment: Thanks so much, the "typeof" helped a lot. I was trying to incorporate MongoDB's "$type" somehow. 
Follow up question though, how do I determine the fieldName value when it changes so often? Is there a way I can tap into it no matter where I am?
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10557386/pedro-pini